# Sending contained object over RIA Services

Tags: .net, silverlight, ria, wcf-ria-services

I have class like this:

```
public class object {
   [Key]
   int number;

   String mystring;

   OtherObject anotherobject;
}
```

WHen i sent this over RIA my silverlight application can see object.number and object.mystring, but not object.anotherobject!!!
What should i do?? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do [Include] and [Association] above the object and the association parameters need to be the other objects [Key]

Also you can send from Server to Client but not CLient to server thats just how RIA works cause it kind of sucks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Include] attribute on referenced classes to indicate that you want those classes serialized as well:

```
public class Monkey 
{
   [Key]   
   int number;
   String mystring;

   [Include]
   OtherObject anotherobject;
}
```

This can also be done in code:

```
public IQueryable<Monkey> GetMonkeys()
{            
   var Monkey = this.Context.Monkey.Include("Monkey.OtherObject");
   return Monkey;
}
```

Some references:

- http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-applications-with-.NET-RIA-Service-Part-3-Adding-DomainService-class.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/22/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-6-poco-and-authentication-provider.aspx

Comment: No this doesn't work i figured it out but maybe actually post about stuff u know??

Comment: Oh, you're right. The references I posted by the people who created RIA Services must be wrong. Glad you figured out the real way to do it.

Comment: Can you post how you got it to work and accept your answer? That way the next person that hits this problem will know how to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the issue is that you have to make the `OtherObject` serializable. The other two variables are primitives and therefore they are already serializable.

For Example:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class BarrieHibbertWrapper
{
   [DataMember]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You will have to add `System.RunTime.Serialization` as a reference.

It could be that you will have to do the same to the class you included in your code.